# find if key exist in array 2 from array 1

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array_1 = array(
    'name' => 'Example Name',
    'company' => 'Intel ',
    'website' => 'WWW.intel.COM',
    'contact' => 'CONTACT@intel.COM',
    'twitter' => 'HTTP://TWITTER.COM/intel',
);

$array_2 = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'field' => 'name',
        'default_field_text' => 'Name Here'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => '3',
        'field' => 'company',
        'default_field_text' => 'COMPENY NAME HERE'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id' => '4',
        'field' => 'website',
        'default_field_text' => 'WWW.WEBSITECOMPENY.COM'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'id' => '5',
        'field' => 'contact',
        'default_field_text' => 'CONTACT@COMPENY.MAIL.COM'
    ),
    4 => array(
        'id' => '6',
        'field' => 'twitter',
        'default_field_text' => 'HTTP://TWITTER.COM/NAME HERE'
    ),
    5 => array(
        'id' => '8',
        'field' => 'facebook',
        'default_field_text' => 'HTTP://FACEBOOK.COM/YOURNAME'
    )
);
```

Hi.. first of all sorry for my English...This is what i'm trying to figure it out,
**array_1** keys are consider as field & form post value, **array_2** have field + default value..

***so i'm trying to output like this***

```
Example Name
Intel
WWW.intel.COM
CONTACT@intel.COM
HTTP://TWITTER.COM/intel
HTTP://FACEBOOK.COM/YOURNAME //from array_2 value
```

my code is here its but its not working.. i know i'm doing it completely wrong

```
foreach($array_2 as $item){
    $text = $item['default_field_text'];
    if($array_1[$item['field']] == $item['field']) $text = $array_1[$item['field']];
    echo $text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
if( x === y)
```

instead of:

```
if(x == y)
```